# how to center newly added object on a zoomed canvas

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I need a way to add an object to the center of the currently visible portion of the canvas.
At any moment, Canvas can be zoomed in by any amount and any section of the zoomed-in canvas can be visible.

How to add an object to the center of the current view portion of the canvas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a RenderTransform you need to use [Inverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.generaltransform.inverse.aspx) transform to compute coordinates in canvas space from zoomed space.

If you have more complex visual tree and transformations, [TransformToVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual.aspx) might help you.

Comment: Yes right now I am using TransformToVisual and using a thumb to get center of current visible area of the view
But this is error-prone :(

Comment: Oh I meant, keeping the thumb floating on a canvas while canvas is moving in the background is error-prone.

I have canvas which can move, expand, zoomed and at any particular time, canvas can be having any part visible on screen
I need to find out center of that visible portion of the canvas.